# Undefined values returned from flickr api

Tags: jquery, html, flickr

While trying to build a simple 10 image gallery of images pulled from flickr API for school i have run into a problem.

My Code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=thor&api_key=[API_KEY]5&per_page=10', function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $(data).find("photo").each(function(index, value) {
            var ident = (value.id);
            var secret_id = (value.secret);
            var farm_id = (value.farm);
            var server_id = (value.server);
            $("#target").append("<p>" + ident + " " + server_id + " " + secret_id + " " + farm_id + "</p>");
        });
    });
});
```

The Output...

"10627683824 undefined undefined undefined" (10 of these with different id values)

I know I am on the right track. If someone can explain to me WHY i am getting the undefined values it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `attr` to get the attributes from the returned XML. Try this:

```
$.get('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=thor&api_key=[API_KEY]&per_page=10', function (data) {
    var items = [];
    $(data).find("photo").each(function (index, value) {
        var ident = value.id;
        var secret_id = $(value).attr('secret');
        var farm_id = $(value).attr('farm');
        var server_id = $(value).attr('server');
        $("#target").append("<p>" + ident + " " + server_id + " " + secret_id + " " + farm_id + "</p>");
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/29hV5/)

The only reason it works for `value.id` is because `id` is a native property.

Comment: This is literally in my clipboard and was about to be pasted :p

Comment: that worked perfectly. How would someone new to jquery and API know that something like id is native and the rest require the attr?

Comment: Glad to help. Knowing the native properties takes knowledge of the underlying javascript DOM elements, nothing to do with jQuery.